# SymPy: unable to simplify rather simple expression

Tags: sympy, simplify

I have an expression (`expr`, see below) that I am unable to simplify in SymPy. For real and positive `x`, `expr` is equivalent to `x**3 + 2*x`, but `simplify` and `refine` do not simplify the expression at all. (Mathematica does the simplication without any effort). 
How to simplify this expression with SymPy?

```
from sympy import *

x = var('x')

expr = 16*x**3/(-x**2 + sqrt(8*x**2 + (x**2 - 2)**2) + 2)**2 - 2*2**(S(4)/5)*x*(-x**2 + sqrt(8*x**2 + (x**2 - 2)**2) + 2)**(S(3)/5) + 10*x

expr1 = simplify(expr) # does nothing

expr2 = refine(expr, Q.positive(x)) # does nothing
```

Comment: It can be done, it's just not nearly as straightforward as Mathematica makes it. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

## It can be done!

I rescind my earlier answer. Your expression can be simplified using Sympy. Here's how:

```
import sympy as sym

x = sym.symbols('x', positive=True)
expr = 16*x**3/(-x**2 + sym.sqrt(8*x**2 + (x**2 - 2)**2) + 2)**2 - 2*2**(sym.S(4)/5)*x*(-x**2 + sym.sqrt(8*x**2 + (x**2 - 2)**2) + 2)**(sym.S(3)/5) + 10*x

sym.simplify(sym.factor(sym.factor(sym.expand(sym.radsimp(expr))), deep=True))
```

Output:

```
x*(x**2 + 2)
```

Basically, I dug through all of the [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html) on [`sympy.simplify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html) until I found that magic combination. Also, you have to define `x` as `positive` when you create the symbol, just as I did in the code above.

## Comment on Mathematica

"Mathematica does the simplication without any effort"

I don't think you should ever underestimate the quantity of time and money that has gone into making the heuristic nightmare that is Mathematica's `Simplify` seem like it "just works". Sadly, in a lot of ways Sympy is still in it's infancy in comparison. `sympy.simplify` is one of those ways.

Comment: What's the use of calling factor on expand? Aren't those functions inverses of each other?

Comment: Maybe you'd think that, but they're definitely not implemented as inverses. And I did test: that is the minimal set of operations that will produce the correct simplified output. You take a single one away (include the `deep` flag), and, at best, you end up with half-simplified garbage.

Comment: Think about it this way: all of the Sympy simplification functions have trouble dealing with nested terms (in that regard, I think that Mathematica's similar). Calling `expand` exposes the innards of the terms for `factor` to then operate on. Supposedly, if the `deep` flag is set `subexpressions will
be factored`. So if that behavior were more robust then perhaps the call to `expand` (and the second call to `factor`) would not be necessary.

Comment: It seems that also `bottom_up(expr, factor)` can do the job.

Comment: You can also just use `factor(expr, deep=True)`.